# Fast rearranging of a text file

Tags: python, multithreading, text, file-io, parallel-processing

I wrote the following code to rewrite a text file in a given order. This order is specified in `gA`. `gA` is a list: `[[fN0,value0],[fN1,value1] ...]`. I sorted this list by value and want to write out respecting this order.

My code works fine, but is very slow on my input (I have an input with 50m rows and it would take 2 months to process it). Therefore, I am looking for ways to fasten this code. Any idea is welcome.

```
for k in gA:
    fN = k[0]
    for lineNum, line in enumerate(slicedFile,start=0):
        num, restOfLine = line.split('\t',1)
        if num == fN:
            out.write(line)
    inp.seek(0)
```

Comment: What's the point of `gA`? Don't you just want to sort the lines in the file based on the value of `num`?

Comment: Why do you `enumerate()`?  You are not using the `lineNum`.  Is this intended or am I pointing a t a thing you want to change?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Actually, the values of num are ids of the different rows (each row begins with a num and this is the way I recognize them)

Comment: @Alfe To be honnest, I enumerate because this is the way I'm used to do it. How would you proceed otherwise?

Comment: If you don't need the numeration, just use `for line in slicedFile:` instead of `for lineNum, line in enumerate(slicedFile, start=0):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the whole file into memory and put all lines in a `dict` of `num` pointing at a `list` of `line`s having that `num` in the beginning.  Then you can iterate once through the `gA` and print all lines from that `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lines = defaultdict(list)
for line in slicedFile:
  num, restOfLine = line.split('\t', 1)
  lines[num].append(line)

for fN, dummy in gA:
  for line in lines[fN]:
    out.write(line)
```

Note: I'm using `defaultdict` just to shorten the code.  If a non-existing element is used in such a `defaultdict`, it gets created automatically (in this case a `list`), so I can just call `.append()` on the element.